# Customizing JSON decoding in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json

I'm trying to customize the parsing of JSON documents in such a way that I can set the class that's used for objects within the document, based on a fixed key in the object.

For example, any objects that occur anywhere in the JSON with a key of "type" that has the value "account" should create an instance of `Account`.

```
{"type": "account", "account_id": "1234"}
```

Objects with a key of "type" that has the value "user" should create an instance of `User`.

```
{"type": "user", "username": "jane", "email": "jane@example.com"}
```

Any other objects in the JSON should decode normally, and there may be multiple account/user style objects embedded anywhere in the document.

For example:

```
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "users": [{"type": "user", "username": "jane", "email": "jane@example.com"}],
    "extra": {"paid": true, "account": {"type": "account", "account_id": "1234"}}
}
```

In Python I'm able to specify a custom decoder that allows me to control how the object is instantiated.

```
class CustomJSONDecoder(json.JSONDecoder):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['object_hook'] = self.dict_to_object
        super(CustomJSONDecoder, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def dict_to_object(self, data):
        identifier = data.get('type')
        if identifier == 'account':
            return Account(data)
        elif identifier == 'user':
            return User(data)
        return data

def loads(content):
    return json.loads(content, cls=CustomJSONDecoder)
```

Similarly in Javascript I can do this...

```
function decoder(key, val) {
    if (val._type === "account") {
        return Account(val);
    } else if (val._type === "user") {
        return User(val);
    }
    return val;
}

function loads(content) {
    return JSON.parse(content, decoder);
}
```

I'm not sure the simplest way to achieve the same thing in Ruby.

I've seen that `JSON.parse` takes an `object_class` parameter, but that's to a fixed class, rather than determined dynamically.

I don't really mind if the end result is achieved through post-processing the parsed JSON, or by occurring during the parse stage.  It may be that the easiest way is parsing the JSON normally and then walking through and altering the resulting data structure, although if that's the case I'd still appreciate some guidance on implementing that.

Comment: Why? Why not just decode the JSON normally, and then modify the returned object? It would be incredibly trivial.

Comment: As mentioned, I don't mind if the operation is performed *during* parsing, or as post processing.  In Python and Javascript the easiest way to achieve the result is during parsing.  I've got plenty of Python & Javascript experience, but I've never used Ruby before so I'm also looking for any help on the post processing stage.

Comment: Updated question to make it more clear that I'm trying to do this against arbitrary documents, rather than for a single object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would certainly be easy to operate on the post-processed JSON. `String#classify` and `String#constantize` are useful here for getting a class from a string by name.

```
parsed = JSON.parse(data)
klass = parsed.delete("type").classify.constantize
instance = klass.new(parsed)
```

### Using manual recursion

After parsing the JSON, you can deserialize certain JSON structures into objects with something like the following:

```
SAFE_TYPES = %w(user account)
def deep_deserialize(data)
  case data
  when Array
    data.map {|value| deep_deserialize(value) }
  when Hash
    deserialized = Hash[*data.flat_map {|k, v| [k, deep_deserialize(v)] }]
    if deserialized.key?("type") && SAFE_TYPES.include?(deserialized["type"])
      klass = deserialized.delete("type").classify.constantize
      klass.new(deserialized)
    else
      deserialized
    end
  else
    data
  end
end
```

This just walks the tree, and any time it finds a hash with a `type` key, it sees if that type is safe to instantiate, and if so, instantiates it with the given attributes.

A small test:

```
require 'active_support/all'
require 'rspec'
require 'pp'

class Base
  def initialize(attributes)
    @attributes = attributes
  end
end

class User    < Base; end
class Account < Base; end
class Admin   < Base; end

json = <<-EOF
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "users": [{"type": "user", "username": "jane", "email": "jane@example.com"}],
    "extra": {"paid": true, "account": {"type": "account", "account_id": "1234"}},
    "bogus": {"type": "admin", "password": "0wn3d"}
}
EOF

pp deep_deserialize JSON.parse(json)
describe "deep_deserialize" do
  subject { deep_deserialize JSON.parse(json) }

  it "should deserialize permitted classes" do
    subject["users"][0].should be_a User
  end

  it "should deserialize in nested hashes" do
    subject["extra"]["account"].should be_a Account
  end

  it "should not deserialize non-permitted classes" do
    subject["bogus"].should be_a Hash
    subject["bogus"]["type"].should == "admin"
  end
end
```

And output:

```
{"version"=>"1.0",
 "users"=>
  [#<User:0x000000023e6050
    @attributes={"username"=>"jane", "email"=>"jane@example.com"}>],
 "extra"=>
  {"paid"=>true,
   "account"=>#<Account:0x000000023e5948 @attributes={"account_id"=>"1234"}>},
 "bogus"=>{"type"=>"admin", "password"=>"0wn3d"}}

deep_deserialize
  should deserialize permitted classes
  should deserialize in nested hashes
  should not deserialize non-permitted classes
```

### Using JSON.load

`JSON.load` takes care of the recursion for us, so we can just use it. This would be much simpler if `JSON.load` used the return values of the proc for the deserialized values, but it doesn't seem to do that, so we're left with inline replacement instead.

```
def deserialize_obj(obj, safe_types = %w(user account))
  type = obj.is_a?(Hash) && obj["type"]
  safe_types.include?(type) ? type.classify.constantize.new(obj) : obj
end

JSON.load(json, proc {|obj|
  case obj
  when Hash
    obj.each {|k, v| obj[k] = deserialize_obj v }
  when Array
    obj.map! {|v| deserialize_obj v }
  end
})
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. Post processing is fine, though I still need to deal with walking the data tree, any examples of how that would look would be greatly appreciated. Incidentally, I don't think I'll be using `classify` - there's only a limited number of types that'll be used, and the data sources can't be trusted so I don't want to open up arbitrary code execution.

Comment: It's worth noting that `classify` just mutates a string into a class name form; `constantize` is the actual lookup method which is dangerous. I'm amending my answer to include a solution for the deep tree walk.

Comment: I may have a much simpler one, now that I'm reading the docs for the json extension. I'll let you know shortly :)

Answer (score 0):

### Pure Ruby and a Dash of Metaprogramming

I'm not sure if I completely understand your issue, but I grok that you want to take a JSON object and convert it to some sort of customizable Ruby object. There are probably a number of approaches, but one approach would be to convert the JSON object into a [Struct](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Struct.html), which you can then modify or pass to another object. For example, using Ruby 2.0:

```
require 'json'

# Use some metaprogramming to define a Struct based on the value of the
# "type" key.
def json_to_struct string
    hash  = JSON.load string 
    klass = hash['type'].capitalize
    hash.delete 'type'
    Class.new Struct.new(klass, *hash.keys)
    Object.const_get("Struct::#{Struct.constants.last}").new *hash.values
end 

my_struct = json_to_struct '{"type": "account", "account_id": "1234"}'
# => #<struct Struct::Account account_id="1234">

my_struct.class.to_s.split('::').last
# => "Account"
```

Note that some of the magic here relies on the ordered hashes provided by MRI 2.0. If you're using a different interpreter that doesn't provide the keys in the order needed to build a Struct, you may want to use [OpenStruct](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) instead.

### Great, a Struct...now what?

Once you have your Struct, you can add additional methods to the class or operate on its values to customize your data in whatever way seems appropriate to you. For example, you can modify the data directly:

```
# Operate directly on a Struct value. Subtract 1,034 from the account ID
# and save the new value back into the Struct.
my_struct['account_id'] = my_struct['account_id'].to_i - 1_034
# => 200

# The new value is now stored in the Struct.
my_struct
# => #<struct Struct::Account account_id=200>
```

Or, you can add behavior to your Struct class with singleton methods. For example:

```
# Add a singleton method to your Struct.
def my_struct.subtract number
  self["account_id"] = account_id - number
end

my_struct.subtract 10
# => 190

my_struct
# => #<struct Struct::Account account_id=190>
```